# Django - Best method for comparing real person names

Tags: python, django

Assuming I have

A) Model:

```
class Person(models.Model)
    first_names: models.CharField()
    last_names: models.CharField()
```

B) Dataset:

```
first_names: "John", last_names: "Smith"
first_names: "John", last_names: "Bar Smith"
first_names: "John Foo", last_names: "Smith"
```

I woul like to see if a person `first_names: "John", last_names: "Smith"` or `first_names: "John", last_names: "Bar Smith"` exists in my Dataset in order to avoid duplicates.

My first though was to use ElasticSearch for this. Are there any "cheaper" methods - perhaps django native - to do this?

Comment: Well, real person names can surely be total dups.

Comment: The thing is that you could have the same name/lastname for different people. Don't you have any other field that is (hopely) unique? Let's say email. Then you compare name-lastname-email, so you know that the person (not the field) is unique.

Comment: I actually combined with email. However, these days it seems like many people have more than one address and that makes duplicate checking a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` with multiple arguments for this:

```
Person.objects.filter(first_name__contains='John', last_name__contains='Smith').exists()
```

To check if queryset returns any data you can use [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) method.

Comment: How would you suggest combining these multiple filter arguments? I tried Q()-ing them, but there seems to be an ending number of combinations of which not all make sense.

Comment: @ShezanKazi if I understand your problem correctly you can use `contains`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#contains